# Update trigger disables functionality of database

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am trying to add a trigger to my SQL DB from phpMyAdmin. 
When applying the trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `download_url` AFTER INSERT ON
`tbl_files` FOR EACH ROW UPDATE tbl_files SET
download = CONCAT('http://website/', url)
WHERE 1
```

When trying to upload a file, I get no results; if I remove the trigger it functions properly.  I need the download column to update with the prefix [http://website/] and value [url].

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a considerably simpler approach - instead of having an `AFTER INSERT` trigger, use a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger and manipulate the incoming row before writing it to the table. You can use the special variable `NEW` to reference this new row:

```
CREATE TRIGGER download_url
BEFORE INSERT ON tbl_files
FOR EACH ROW 
  SET NEW.download = CONCAT('http://website', NEW.url);
END;
```